# formatting vector output using iomanip

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having some trouble here. I have a file that looks like this (here's a snippet)

```
Sophia F 22158
Emma F 20791
Isabella F 18931
Jacob M 18899
Mason M 18856
Ethan M 17547
```

and I want to put each name, and the name's respective number into seperate vectors. For example, I would have 4 vectors:
1 for women's names and 1 for women's numbers, and the same for men's and men's numbers. (so 4 total)

I have this code, which will go through the file and pull out these elements and put them in vectors.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
        getline (inputFile, inputLine);
        ss.str(inputLine); //ss is a string stream
        ss >> name >> gender >>  popularity;
        if (gender == 'M') {
            mNames[i] = name;
            mFrequency[i] = popularity;
        } else if (gender == 'F') {
            fNames[i] = name;
            fFrequency[i] = popularity;
        }

        ss.clear();

    }
```

and I use this method to print it out:

```
cout << counter << " Most Popular Baby Names" << endl << endl;
    cout << left << setw(15) << "Girls" ;
    cout << right << setw(9) << "Frequency" <<"      ";
    cout << left << setw(15) << "Boys";
    cout << right << setw(9) << "Frequency" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i ++) {
        cout << left << setw(15) << fNames[i] ;
        cout << right << setw(9) << fFreq[i] <<"      ";
        cout << left << setw(15) << mNames[i];
        cout << right << setw(9) << mFreq[i] << endl;
   {
```

but then I get this output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x0ta.png

But I would like for it to be like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSIX9.png

So I'm thinking I either need to go through before I print and remove all the whitespace/0's in these vectors, or I need to check while I'm printing out. Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: You need to sort both vectors, then print out the top 5. I will suggest not using parallel vectors when doing something like this, instead use OOP to accomplish this

Comment: If you have less than 'counter' elements and you're populating an array of strings with 'counter' zeroes (and you want 'counter' elements to be printed), there's no solution. Consider reducing the 'counter' number of elements to the maximum you can find in the file

Comment: I would love to learn a more efficient way, but I don't really have the knowledge and my teacher is very specific about using 4 vectors to complete this task. The names in the file are already sorted, so is there some way I can say something like:
if (mFreq !=0)
   mName[nextEmptyElement] = name;
?

Comment: Oh, you're saying I need to pull out the top five males, and then pull out the top five females seperately!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks guys.

I used two separate while loops, one for each set of arrays. In between them I reset the ifstream back to the beginning. This way, it goes through until each vector has 5 non-zero elements.